# how to add a minimum line order value shopware 6

Tags: minimum, shopware6, items

I would like to know if there is an option to enable a sort of minimum line value?
for exemple 1 part costs 0.06 that i enable a minimum rule of minimum 1 euro value to all items. so this would be 16/17pcs.

Hope someone knows if this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

There's the `minPurchase` field of a `product` (or "Min. order quantity" within the details of a product in the administration. However this relates to the quantity of an item not the total price of all items. So in your example you'd have to set `minPurchase` to 17 if in the cart the line items for that product should amount to a minimum of 1 Euro.

If it is worth your time, you could do this programmatically by adding a custom field to the product where you enter the minimum monetary amount. Then subscribe to `sales_channel.product.loaded` and set the `minPurchase` field dynamically depending on the custom field value.

```php
public function loaded(EntityLoadedEvent $event): void
{
    /** @var SalesChannelProductEntity $product */
    foreach ($event->getEntities() as $product) {
        $customFields = $product->getCustomFields();
        $minMonetaryPurchase = $customFields['min_monetary_purchase'] ?? null;

        if (!$minMonetaryPurchase) {
            continue;
        }

        $minPurchase = ceil($minMonetaryPurchase / $product->getCalculatedPrice()->getUnitPrice());
        $product->setMinPurchase((int) $minPurchase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,

but that means i have to check all products +- 30K of them right? is their a way to do the calculation in the shoppingcart? so each line gets checked before finalizing the order or when adding a line into the cart?

Comment: `sales_channel.product.loaded` is dispatched whenever a product is loaded in the storefront, e.g. also when a product is converted to a line item and added to the cart. If you want to use a custom field because the min. monetary value differs for each product, that's what you'd have to set in all products. If it's always the same value you obviously may as well just hardcode the value and not use custom fields.

Comment: It's always going to be the same value for all products so minimum price needs to be 1 euro. were can i put this code into shopware files? and will it remain if an update has been released?

Comment: You have to create a plugin an [add a subscriber](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cart validator, es [described in the docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-validator)

You implement your own `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartValidatorInterface`, register, add your own error extending `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Error\Error`

Register it in your services.xml

```
<services>
    <service id="Swag\BasicExample\Core\Checkout\Cart\Custom\CustomCartValidator">
        <tag name="shopware.cart.validator"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

And this way you can run through all line items/products in your cart, validate them and throw an error if one of them doesn't validate.

Comment: This is another valid approach. However this will not prevent a customer from adding products in a quantity below the minimum in the first place. The validator may only immediately remove invalid line items from the cart afterwards. Hence why I'd still recommend setting the `minPurchase` property as it will not only prevent line items below a certain quantity from being added to the cart but also change the minimum value in the quantity selection on the product detail page, preventing customers from choosing a lower quantity in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @dneustadt very valid points!